# cash on delivery

Tags: magento2.2, shipping-methods, cash-on-delivery

Can someone help me with an extension for cash on delivery? So that, in the back end we want to choose for which countries cash on delivery will be available and also just only **for country Jordan** I can choose for **which city** cash on delivery will be available and also to be able to set price for COD. in short, I want to be able to choose countries that I can offer COD and since we are located in Amman, Jordan we want to offer cash on delivery free for Amman and charge for other cities.

Comment: Please specify Magento version?

Comment: we are using magento 2.2.2 community

Answer (score 0):

This extension is wonderful one, and it is free

https://webshopapps.com/uk/magento-1-extensions/wsa-standalone/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html

you can setup Shipping methods as much as you want per city and even per zipcode if you want.

After you install this extension, export the CSV file then put the free shipping for Amman and rename it **Cash on Delivery** (You can put the name inside the CSV file), and put the cost for the another cities/countries

I hope this extension will help you

Comment: please check now, it looks like they add the ssl to their link, I just changed the http to https

Comment: Thank you, it works.